# disable text box selection brush

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have several text boxes in my project and when the program is running and select one of them, a white rectangle appears on back of text box and caret starts blinking, is there a way to get rid of this white box and caret  ? So when tapping on text box just clear the text inside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to get rid of this white box and caret

The white box is actually the `BorderElement` of the detault [TextBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx). You can change the default style of the `Textbox` to what you want. For example, commented out the time lines inside the style which is changing the `BorderElement` background color and then the white background color will not appear.

```
<!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
```

For caret, you may set the `TextBox` as [`ReadOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_IsReadOnly) once the `Textbox` get focused, or let the other controls to get focus to let the `TextBox` lose focus so that the cursor may not appear.

> So when tapping on text box just clear the text inside

For this, you can clear the text when the `Textbox` [got focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_GotFocus).

Following is a simple demo may implement what you want you may reference:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">        
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <Grid
                                                x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}"
                                                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                <TextBlock
                                                    x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                    FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                    FontSize="12"
                                                    FontStyle="Normal"
                                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                    Text="&#xE10A;" />
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                                    Duration="0"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                    To="0" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border
                            x:Name="BorderElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                        <ContentPresenter
                            x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,0,8"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                            FontWeight="Normal"
                            x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <ScrollViewer
                            x:Name="ContentElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                            IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                            IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                            VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                            ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                        <ContentControl
                            x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            IsTabStop="False" />
                        <Button
                            x:Name="DeleteButton"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            MinWidth="34"
                            Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="Gridroot" Padding="50">
   <Button x:Name="btnforfocus"></Button>   
   <TextBox
       x:Name="txttest"
       Width="300"
       Height="50"
       Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"
       Background="Azure"
       BorderThickness="0"           
       FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="White"
       Text="aaaaa"     
       GotFocus="txttest_GotFocus"            
       />
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
private void txttest_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txttest.Text = "";
    try
    {           
        btnforfocus.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
        //txttest.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

You can change the style for a  `Textbox` by setting its properties  or update the control's default style and template. More details please reference [`Textbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox).

Comment: Thank you so much, It was very helpful